# what is the best way to export or transfer a 6gb Google big query table for use in mysql?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to export a big query result which the table is 6gb. Google has a limit of 1gb per file, is there another way to move the whole file? I need to get it into a MySql table. Thanks!

Comment: Your doubt is about retrieve this data or insert this data in the MySQL?

Comment: You should retrieve only parts of the data, one part a time.

Answer (score 1):

The limit you read is only for one single file, there are other ways to export unlimited size.

There are 3 ways to export your data:

1. Single URI (1 file, limit 1GB, most probably you are using this)

> ['gs://my-bucket/file-name.json']
>
> Creates:
>
> gs://my-bucket/file-name.json

2. Single wildcard URI (multiple files are created each 1GB)

> ['gs://my-bucket/file-name-*.json']
>
> Creates:
>
> gs://my-bucket/file-name-000000000000.json
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-000000000001.json
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-000000000002.json   ...

3. Multiple wildcard URIs (this needs Hadoop)

> gs://my-bucket/file-name-{worker number}-*.json
>
> Creates:
>
> This example assumes that BigQuery creates 80 sharded files in each
>   partition.
>
> gs://my-bucket/file-name-1-000000000000.json
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-1-000000000001.json
>   ...
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-1-000000000080.json
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-2-000000000000.json
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-2-000000000001.json
>   ...
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-2-000000000080.json
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-3-000000000000.json
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-3-000000000001.json
>   ...
>   gs://my-bucket/file-name-3-000000000080.json

Read more at:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#exportingmultiple

Comment: I got it now, added *

Comment: now I am getting an error during the export that access is denied, is this a bucket permission setting? If so what should i set it to?